# solace - lNFO logging in console - how to disable it

Tags: solace

By default the INFO logging is printing in the console how to disable it ?

How to browse the message in the solace mq ? do we have any tool for this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Logging configuration is dependant on the platform of the application. The Solace JMS and JCSMP API logging uses Jakarta Commons Logging to support different logging frameworks, such as log4j or java.util.logging. The other answer by user Farside shows how to change the logging level if you are using log4j with the Solace JMS API.

You can find more information about logging in your specific platform in the Solace Messaging API guides or in the integration guides provided on the Solace Systems Developer Portal.

To see information about the spooled messages on a queue in Solace, you can use the CLI or SolAdmin.

In the CLI, the command is:

```
show queue <queueName> message-vpn <vpnName> messages detail
```

This will allow you to see information on each message in the queue, such as the date spooled, message size, sequence number, etc.

In SolAdmin, you can view the equivalent information by navigating to the 'Endpoints' tab and selecting the 'Durable Queues' view. From this view, you can double click on the queue in the list and select the 'Messages' tab. You can double click on a specific message to view more information.

To view the full contents of a spooled message, you can create a Queue Browser. This is a client that can look at messages spooled on a queue in order of oldest to newest without consuming them. A full description of a Queue Browser is provided in Chapter 9, "Working with Guaranteed Messages" of the Solace Messaging Platform Feature Guide. Details about creating a Queue Browser are provided in the Solace Messaging APIs Developer Guide.
These documents are available on the Solace Systems developer portal at this link:
http://dev.solacesystems.com/docs/product-documentation/

Answer (score 2):

Solace JMS API logging is very similar to configuring any other Spring 
Framework logging. They say, to define the level of logging use:

```
log4j.category.com.solacesystems.jms=DEBUG
log4j.category.com.solacesystems.jcsmp=DEBUG
```

More information can be found [here](http://www.solacesystems.com/wp-content/uploads/resources/Solace-JMS-Integration-with-Spring-v4.0.pdf): section "*6.1 How to enable Solace JMS API logging*". By default info logs will be written to the console.

Comment: I do have added the below properties in the log4j.properties :

Comment: log4j.rootCategory=ERROR, stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %t %c{2}:%L - %m%n
log4j.category.com.solacesystems.jms=ERROR
log4j.category.com.solacesystems.jcsmp=ERROR

Comment: May 4, 2016 11:29:21 PM com.solacesystems.jcsmp.protocol.impl.TcpClientChannel call
INFO: Connecting to host 'orig=tcp://10.80.97.150:55555, scheme=tcp://, host=10.80.97.150, port=55555' (host 1 of 1, smfclient 368, attempt 1 of 1, this_host_attempt: 1 of 1)
May 4, 2016 11:29:21 PM com.solacesystems.jcsmp.protocol.impl.TcpClientChannel call
INFO: Connected to host 'orig=tcp://10.80.97.150:55555, scheme=tcp://, host=10.80.97.150, port=55555' (smfclient 368)
May 4, 2016 11:29:21 PM com.solacesystems.jcsmp.protocol.impl.TcpClientChannel executeJndiQuery

Comment: INFO: Error Response (404) - Not Found
May 4, 2016 11:29:21 PM com.solacesystems.jcsmp.protocol.impl.TcpClientChannel close
INFO: Channel Closed (smfclient 368)
May 4, 2016 11:29:21 PM com.solacesystems.jms.SolQueueReceiver handleEvent

Comment: May 4, 2016 11:29:21 PM com.solacesystems.jms.SolMessageConsumer start
INFO: Entering start().
May 4, 2016 11:29:21 PM com.solacesystems.jms.SolMessageConsumer setDelayStartRequested
INFO: Message Consumer start delay requested.
May 4, 2016 11:29:21 PM com.solacesystems.jms.SolMessageConsumer start
INFO: Leaving start().
May 4, 2016 11:29:21 PM com.solacesystems.jms.SolQueueReceiver <init>
INFO: SolQueueReceiver created